# How do you implement trees using vectors or arraylist?

Tags: java

if possible please post some sample codes.  Because we have a project wherein we need to set up locations within a map, and connect those locations with a line.  Other than we also need to have a starting and end point in which we need to find a path going from the designated starting to the end point.

Comment: Is this an assignment where you have to make your own tree? Java already has a built-in Tree type: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Comment: Without information on what kind of tree you want to implement, this question is unanswerable.  Besides, the question borders on "send me codez" and "please do my homework for me" ... both of which are frowned on.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
class Node {
    Node(Object object) {
        this.object=object;
    }
    Object object;
    List<Node> children=new ArrayList<Node>();
    public String toString() {
        return object.toString();
    }
    static void traverse(Node node) {
        System.out.println(node);
        for(Node child:node.children)
            traverse(child);
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node root=new Node("root");
        root.children.add(new Node("child 1"));
        root.children.add(new Node("child 2"));
        Node.traverse(root);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please if you did not read about Dijkstra, its the first you have to do if you wanna find a method to get the best(the shortest) route between two nodes...